# " Буквы должны быть добавочными (некорневыми) " или "(Буквы должны быть добавочными (не корневыми)"?

Tags: орфография

" Буквы должны быть добавочными (некорневыми) " или "(Буквы должны быть добавочными (не корневыми)"?

Comment: Сказали бы сразу, что это из арабистики. Я б голову не ломал. 
Слитно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А из какой области это? Добавочный vs корневой?
Меня откровенно смущают сами термины.
Впрочем, если "некорневой" используется именно как термин, логично слитное написание. Если нет - то раздельное. 
Смысл сентенции при этом весьма туманен в любом случае.